# Twitter Posting From Classic ASP Application, Should I use PHP?

Tags: php, asp-classic, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have created a Twitter App on the twitter developer site and have the Consumer key and Consumer secret.  Now I want to integrate twitter into our Classic ASP Application.

There is not much available while browsing around.  Any genius here have a working solution for Classic ASP? I am referring to the OAUTH parts and the post of message to twitter

Would it be easier to use PHP pages within the classic ASP site?

Any advice, help, tips, links would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using .NET code to produce the code that does the integration with Twitter.  Package it in a way the ASP page can get to it.

For the packaging, I see some obvious options:

- a re-usable COM component.
- a standalone EXE.

The EXE idea is probably simpler.  You just invoke it from the ASP page with WScript.Exec.

You could start with [this example](http://cheesoexamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TweetIt).  It posts tweets to twitter, authenticates via OAuth. It's written in C# and compiles to a standalone EXE.